# How to inject an object to Serialize to File?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

The problem is simple, I want to create a method to serialize and another to open it by passing any object structure. I have the following which is what I believed should work but, guess what, it doesn't:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
                    list.Add("aaa");
                    list.Add("bbb");

                    FileSystem.SerializeToFile(list, "");
                    List<string> anotherList = FileSystem.OpenSerialized(typeof(List<string>), "");



    public class FileSystem
    {
        public static void SerializeToFile(object toSerialize, string fileName)
        {
            XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            writer.Serialize(file, toSerialize);
            file.Close();
        }

        public static object OpenSerialized(Type type, string fileName)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
            object something = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return something;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer’s constructor requires a reference to the type of object it should work, slightly modified your code to fit to requirement.

```
public class FileSystem
{
    public static void SerializeToFile<T>(T toSerialize, string fileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        writer.Serialize(file, toSerialize);
        file.Close();
    }

    public static T OpenSerialized<T>(string fileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        object something = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return (T)something;
    }
}
```

and now we can use this as

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("aaa");
list.Add("bbb");

FileSystem.SerializeToFile(list, @"d:\test.txt");
List<string> anotherList = FileSystem.OpenSerialized<List<string>>(@"d:\test.txt");
```